# C++ returning locally allocated dynamic memory without leak?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

I am learning about C++ in school and creating a string class for an assignment.  I have a couple of questions:

First, will the following create a memory leak?

```
MyString operator() (int sliceStart, int sliceEnd) {
    sliceStart = sliceStart%_len;
    if(sliceStart < 0)
        sliceStart = _len + sliceStart;
    sliceEnd = sliceEnd%_len;
    if(sliceEnd < 0)
        sliceEnd = _len + sliceEnd;
    char* temp = new char[_len + 1];

    if(sliceStart == sliceEnd)
        return *this;
    int i;
    if(sliceStart < sliceEnd)
        for(i = 0; sliceStart < sliceEnd; ++sliceStart && ++i)
            temp[i] = _str[sliceStart];
    else if(sliceStart > sliceEnd) {
        for(i = 0; sliceStart < _len; ++sliceStart && ++i)
            temp[i] = _str[sliceStart];
        for(int k = 0; k < sliceEnd; ++i && ++k)
            temp[i] = _str[k];
    }
    temp[i] = '\0';
    //delete [] temp
    return MyString(temp);
}
```

And if so, will adding the commented delete line return a valid value since it is freed right before the return.  Or is it possible that the memory could possibly be snatched up between the two lines?

*(I know that in this particular case I could simply create a MyString object before the return, but I am curious as if I HAD to return the temp char*)

**What is the common/proper way to manage dynamic local memory that you also wish to return by value?**

Comment: `First, will the following create a memory leak?` - valgrind is a great tool for that.

Comment: Yup, that's definitely a memory leak.

Comment: Depends. Does the destructor of MyString `delete[]` the buffer? Should it (consider copies - you'll need to override copy assignment operator etc)? You ought to be using smart pointers.

Comment: The copy constructor takes a const so it doesnt alter it.  As far as smart pointers, the assignment (and my small amount of knowledge) are more suited to learning about the language rather than learning how to actually use it in any real life way (from what I've been told...)  Thanks for the help!

Comment: When `sliceStart == sliceEnd`, you do nothing with variable `temp` that you just allocated memory.  Yes, a leak.

Comment: Yes, it's a leak, unless the constructor deletes the string it gets (which is generally a bad idea).  It would be easiest to avoid this efficiently in this case, if you can use C++11 and know move semantics, by creating the MyString object, deleting the temp buffer, and then returning the local MyString object with a std::move().

Comment: Thank you Chux I had not even noticed that!

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but is buffer just a generic term for what I am doing with temp in relation to MyString?  Or are you talking about a specific buffer I am unaware of?  Is Move() used because it is more efficient then return by value?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there's a memory leak in your code, you allocate memory and then potentially return a different value on the next line.

Use encapsulation to help the user understand the lifetime of any allocations; either use something like std::shared_ptr or create a class that wraps ownership of the allocation.